# Which popular/high-profile web applications support two-factor authentication?

Tags: facebook, google, security, authentication

I'm aware that both [Google](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744) and [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150172618258920) offer two-factor authentication, by sending an SMS to your phone under certain circumstances.

What other popular or high-profile web applications support two-factor authentication? I'd like to know which services I should turn on two-factor authentication for, since (at least for the two listed), it isn't the default.

Comment: I don't really understand why this was closed. It clearly pertains to web applications as per the FAQ. It's focused on users, not developers. And most of all, it's useful - it guides folks towards (potentially) more secure web applications, and could provide a useful checklist of apps to enable two-factor auth on. Can someone please clarify why it was closed?

Comment: Questions about polling or lists or subjective popular X for Y are off-topic for this site

Comment: Is there a way I can reword or rephrase this to make it more useful?

Comment: As of august 2012, Dropbox [offers it too](https://blog.dropbox.com/index.php/another-layer-of-security-for-your-dropbox-account/).

Answer (score 2):

- **Amazon Web Services** (AWS) supports two-factor authentication in the
  form of an RSA Token or using Google Authenticator
- **LastPass** also offers two-factor login using Google Authenticator
- **[PayPal](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Tips-from-Moderators/PayPal-Security-Key/td-p/433633)** offers two-factor SMS authentication

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about PayPal (although it looks like they've done it a dumb way: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Tips-from-Moderators/PayPal-Security-Key/td-p/433633).